# Custom ListView does not show up

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I am trying to use a custom `ListView` inside a `Fragment` using also a custom `CursorAdapter`, but so far I was unable to display the `ListView`.

What am i doing wrong?

My `Fragment`

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MyListFragment extends Fragment {

    private CustomcursorAdapter mCustomcursorAdapter;
    private ListView mListView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mylist, container, false);

        //CursorAdapter
        mCustomcursorAdapter = new CustomcursorAdapter(view.getContext(), null, 0);

        //ListView
        mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemslist);
        mListView.setAdapter(mCustomcursorAdapter);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

My MainActivity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        if (fragmentManager.findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
            MyListFragment myListFragment = new MyListFragment();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, myListFragment).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

CustomcursorAdapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomcursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public CustomcursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView textview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemTextView);
        textview.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME_ITEM)));
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.itemslist, parent, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: post CustomcursorAdapter

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Custom CursorAdapter posted!

Comment: @ivoencarnacao you initialize your adapter with a null cursor - no data > nothing to display > no list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I am doing.

In the fragment, I am doing everything in the onActivityCreated() like this:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View campainview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.campaignview, container, false);

        return campainview;
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            String[] s = {"a","b","c","d","b","c","d","b","c","d","b","c","d","b","c","d","b","c","d"};

            ArrayList<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(String s1:s){

                aList.add(s1);

            }

            ListView lv1= (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.campaignListView);
            lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,aList));

        }
```

This work's for me and basically what you can do is that instead of using this adapter iv'e used, you can use you cursor adapter. If it's still not working, then the issue is with the cursor adapter or probably the values are null that's coming from the database.

Let me know if this is working.. Good Luck .. :)